# Are PWAs backed up on iOS?

Tags: ios, backup

Are [Progressive Web Apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app) added to the iOS homescreen part of data backed up and restored via USB?

In particular, are both the app icons and their content (i.e. cookies, IndexedDB data etc.) restored?

Comment: What does PWA stand for?

Comment: @nohillside Progressive Web App https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app. I've edited the question.

Comment: They don't appear to have much support if any on iOS.  Wouldn't this make it a moot point?

Comment: iOS added support for [PWA manifests in iOS 11.3](https://caniuse.com/?search=pwa) (March 2018). Subsequent versions of iOS have further improved support.